# Are there any easy hiking daytrips up mountains in Lofoten, Norway?

Tags: hiking, mountaineering, norway

I realise that's a pretty big area, but we're going to be there for 6 days and we have a car so we can go prettty much wherever. We're not big on climbing - anything requiring equipment is out, we should be able to do it with just our boots and some water :)

Obviously there is some information online, but it's mostly in Norwegian, and whilst I can read Norwegian I don't find that the information is very clear or helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buy a hiking map once there, they should be available in bookshops and tourist offices. The map shows marked trails which are walkable without the need for special equipment. The paths can be rocky, slippery and steep in places though. 
For example on Moskenesoya there are trails from Fredvang to romantic secluded beaches and a trail from Moskenes to the mountain hut Munkebu and mountaintop Hermanssdalstinden.

Online hiking maps can be found [here](http://ut.no/map/page/maptool/274453).

Answer (score 4):

the question is a bit old (2012) but there might be people still searching for an answer to : where and how to walk in the Lofoten Island? I asked myself the same question and I found a web site (in English and in French) which is dedicated to this subject. You will find many pages with day-walks description, maps, pictures, and free-downladable gps tracks. So you might want to have a look at it, as it may help you preparing your trip, as much as it did for me : [www.hiking-lofoten.net](http://www.hiking-lofoten.net)

Antonio

Answer (score 3):

There are also excellent hiking books that describe hikes along with their difficulty. Even if the description may take some work to decipher (although with a dictionary and some time you should be able to), the route sketches, estimate for duration and difficulty can be quite helpful.

I recommend *På tur i Lofoten* which contains a whopping 193 descriptions of hikes, anything from a short 1 hour stroll to an arduous 8 hour scramble. You can order this book directly from [Lofoten Turlag](http://lofoten.turistforeningen.no/index.php), or ask them where you can buy it locally.